# Difference Between Test Design Specification and Test Design Document

Tags: testing

Could anyone please explain or give pointers for the difference between a **Test Design Specification** and **Test Design Document**. I initially thought they were the same thing until I started seeing varying templates for each of them.

Software Design Specification templates were consistent and contained:

- Features to be tested
- Approach
- Test Identification
- Pass/fail criteria

Software Design Document templates were inconsistent and sometimes appearing like supersets of the Software Design Specification, hence my confusion. Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From continuous research I figured out they are in fact the same thing but most of the time the documentation is called **Test Design Specification** and not **Test Design Document**. The slight variation in content depends on the business, organization, etc. They should however contain the items listed in the question. The links below confirm this:

- http://www.badtesting.com/test-documentation/test-design-specification/
- ftp://medical.nema.org/MEDICAL/Dicom/Geninfo/GUIDELIN/tdv2l3.htm